# How to delete a real time module in cumulocity?

Tags: complex-event-processing, cumulocity

To delete an existing module the documentation (http://cumulocity.com/guides/reference/real-time-statements/) says to do a DELETE request against `/cep/module/<<moduleId>>`. But this results in a response status 500 with the reason that "Request method 'DELETE' not supported".
What is the correct request to delete a single module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation gives the wrong path. It needs to be `/cep/modules/<<moduleId>>` instead of `/cep/module/<<moduleId>>`. This can be seen by debugging the behaviour of the web-GUI.

Comment: The same seems to be true for updates via PUT: they also use /cep/modules/<<moduleId>>, and not /cep/module/<<moduleId>>. In addition, "Modify a Module with statements" doesn't really seem to use multipart/form-data (as creation does), but just a simple text/plain.

Comment: Well spotted! I fixed this, it should be online as soon as Jenkins wakes up.

Comment: Cool, @André! Could You verify the content-type of the statement-update as well? It says multipart/form-data, but for me it only works as simple text/plain.

Comment: I will check with support and update the docs. It looks to me like you can do text/plain with PUT to set the text, or multipart/form-data with POST to upload a file.